# Access element by index with a forEach command

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

i want to **access value by index** because i need to loop on the half of the list and display value on two column... so i will need to use index value + x

```
<c:forEach var="endValue" items="${endValue.list}" end="${lngth-1}" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value="${endValue.list[status.index+5].id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

display tag value is not valid

Edit:

```
//controler
@ModelAttribute("endValue")
public EndValueListWrapper populateDataList() {
    final EndValueListWrapper listForm = new EndValueListWrapper();
    ...
    return listForm
}

public class EndValueListWrapper {

   private List<EndValueForm> list;

   // get and set for this list
}

public class EndValueForm{
   private Strind id
   ...
}
```

Comment: why `+5` if you're saying two columns? mind giving a better explanation?

Comment: only an example... you can remove +5, anyway that don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this won't work as you expect. Check out the [JSTL tag lib reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html). `endValue` is a single instance inside of the items collection, so trying to iterate over `endValue.list` and calling each instance in that collection endValue makes no sense. Where is `lngth` defined? You shouldn't even need to set the `end`explicitly if you're going to length -1.

```
<c:forEach items="${teams}" varStatus="status">
   <c:set var="desiredTeam" value="${teams[status.index+5]}" /> 
   <c:out value="${desiredTeam.id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

...or something similar.

Comment: The first part of the answer is correct, but the second part is not. status is not a String. It's an instance of LoopTagStatus, which has an index property. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html. If you just remove the last part of the answer, I'll cancel my downvote.

Comment: lngth is defined before... it's value is half size value of the lenght of the list, status.index to get loop counter var

Comment: Oops, guess I got confused by the formatting of the tag reference page. The expected input value of the attribute is a string, not the result, which you have correctly noted is a LoopTagStatus. Whoops!

Comment: @Visionary: the code snippet is still incorrect. It should be value="${teams[status.index + 5]}"

Comment: <c:forEach items="${endValue.list}" varStatus="status">
    <c:set var="desiredTeam" value="${endValue[status.index]}" /> 
    <c:out value="${desiredTeam.id}"/>  
    </c:forEach>  i get, don't know how to iterate over items

Comment: That still won't work. If you're trying to iterate over `endValue.list` (a nested collection inside of the `endValue` object), trying to access `endValue[status.index]` is invalid. You would want to set the variable to `endValue.list[status.index]`. Note that these are really bad variable names. Perhaps posting more of the relevant surrounding snippet would make your intention clearer.

Comment: it's the only code i have  
    <c:if test="${fn:length(endValue.list) %2==0}">
    <fmt:parseNumber value="${fn:length(endValue.list)/2 - (fn:length(endValue.list)/2)%1}"  
    type="number" var="lngth" integerOnly="true"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${fn:length(endValue.list) %2==1}">
    <fmt:parseNumber value="${fn:length(endValue.list)/2 - (fn:length(endValue.list)/2)%1 +1}" 
    type="number" var="lngth" integerOnly="true"/>
    </c:if>

Comment: Yuck. The error is likely in the controller/servlet/whatever you have passing values into the JSP. Your endValue.list is likely not what you're expecting. 

You should probably pass it explicitly to the JSP with a better name along with the desired ending value already pre-calculated. Views are best left dumb with only simple display logic inside of them.

Comment: <c:forEach var="endValue" items="${endValue.list}" end="${lngth-1}" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value="${endValue.id}"/>
 </c:forEach>  
 don't thinks it's how i pass value to the jsp because theses code work
 the problem is how to access endValue[status.index+lngth].id

Comment: added some info about controler and data model

Comment: You should probably return listform.getList() instead. Make the model attribute endValueList. That'll make it easy to access the variable in the JSP. If you really need to get the length too, you should probably do the calculation in the controller method and return a command object that contains both the list and the length. 

If you can, you may want to consider using Grails. It simplifies a lot of this stuff for you with scaffolding, and there are great tutorials out there.